# Certificate Invalid on Cisco RV325 VPN Router

Tags: networking, router, certificate

My office bought a new RV325 VPN router recently. I noticed immediately after updating the firmware that the router's certificate is invalid. The "My Certificate" screen in the router GUI shows that the certificate is valid from 2022 to 2032. This is causing warning messages to appear in my browser. Also, our off-site Exchange server is blocking emails from the router due to this issue, which means I cannot email logs to myself or anyone else at work.

Is there a solution to this problem besides getting our own certificate from a CA?

I gave this question to the Cisco Support Community a few days ago, but it has received 0 views...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am by no means an expert in Cisco gear (AKA, please don't down vote me :), however if you are just looking for a SSL certificate, then you may be able to fiddle with https://letsencrypt.org.  You can just get a new SSL cert there, unless its as to be a specialized one.

Outside of that, you would normally need to go back to whoever issued the certificate (presumably Cisco) and get them to issue a new one?  Fundamentally, you cannot change a certificate.

Lastly, you may check the system time on both the router and the device trying to connect.  If it is way off that can cause problems too.